# self-referencing relationship in entity model

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am building a spring mvc app with hibernate to interact with a third party database that uses a transitive closure table to manage nested subtype and supertype relationships between millions of different types of vehicles stored in a `vehicles` table. There is also a `vehicles_transitiveclosure` table that stores lists of subtypes and supertypes so that a user can pull all ancestors or all descendents of a specific `vehicleid`.  (Car, van, truck, etc.  Car has subtypes sedan, wagon, etc. With many levels of nesting.)

I created a `vehicle` entity in my spring mvc app, but I am not sure how to represent the transitive closure table in spring mvc.

```
vehicles table
    vehicleid(pk)
    other fields

vehicles_transitiveclosure table
    subtypeid(fk to vehicleid)
    supertypeid(fk to vehicleid)
    other fields
```

I hesitate to treat `vehicles_transitiveclosure` as a junction table because there are a few other fields in each row of `vehicles_transitiveclosure`.  Also, it is a self-referencing relationship for the vehicles entity.  How should I set up my entity model to represent this relationship?

The reason for the transitive closure table is that it enables fast access to all ancestors or all descendents of a given vehicle.  The alternative would be a very resource intensive iterative algorithm to retrieve all the nested levels of subtype and supertype relationships stored in other tables.